# Count the value from the list

Tags: freemarker

I'm setting up a synesty flow and I need to know how many ArticleNumber in the ArticleNumber list.

E.g
Here are the ArticleNumber list

```
35361,35361,35361,205,09308943528,093089435281,093089435281
```

I want to know how many ArticleNumber "09308943528" in the list

I've tried the `?contains` but its only a boolean value.

```
<#if MainArticleNumberList!?contains('${ArticleNumber!}')>true<#else>false</#if>
```

I expect the output number depends on how many ArticleNumber in the list, in the example above it will show 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are before FreeMarker 2.3.29, and thus can't use `?filter`, you can still do this:

```
<#assign cnt = 0>
<#list MainArticleNumberList as articleNumber>
  <#if articleNumber == '09308943528'>
    <#assign cnt++>
  </#if>
</#list>
${cnt}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [filter](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_filter) with size to calculate count:

```
${MainArticleNumberList?filter(x -> x=="09308943528")?sequence?size}
```

Use [seq_contains](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_seq_contains) freemarker builtin for sequences:

```
<#if MainArticleNumberList?seq_contains("09308943528")>true<#else>false</#if>
```

> Tells if the sequence contains the specified value (according the == operator of the template language, not according Java's Object.equals). It has 1 parameter, the value to find.

Comment: thanks, but this only returns as boolean, I need to determine how many ArticleNumber in MainArticleNumberList http://prntscr.com/p43upy

Comment: @AaronMerin true, updated, use answer `${MainArticleNumberList?filter(x -> x=="09308943528")?sequence?size}`

Comment: sorry but it gives me an error http://prntscr.com/p44ctt http://prntscr.com/p44euw

Comment: @AaronMerin you need the latest freemarker 2.3.29 https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_3_29.html

Comment: oic thankyou!, i'll check how synesty upgrade their freemarker.

Comment: `?sequence` is usually not needed for this. It's only needed if `MainArticleNumberList` doesn't support `?size`.

Comment: @ddekany hello, i tried the filter but its always give me 0 output even they are in the list. https://prnt.sc/papwfq can you please check?

Comment: `MainArticleNumberList` is a string, not a sequence (unless Synesty Studio converts it to list). You need `MainArticleNumberList?split(',')` to convert it to a sequence. But, if it's a string, then FreeMarker had to give an error. As you instead get some kind of list, I suspect `MainArticleNumberList` is undefined in that column, and then the `!` operator converts it to an empty list (try `MainArticleNumberList!?size` to know).

Answer (score 0):

```
out = [1,2,3,1,1,1]

print(out.count(1))
```

Comment: hello, I tried to assign the ArticleList in variable and used .count, i dont know why it not reads the .count as function here.. please take a look on Screenshot
http://prntscr.com/p43er9

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
[#assign numbers = [1,1,2,3,4,4,0,5,0,6,0,8,9]]
[#assign words = ["hello","bye","hello"]]

[#function getOccurrencesCount sequence item]
    [#local occurrencesCount = 0]
    [#list sequence as i]
        [#if i == item]
            [#local occurrencesCount++]
        [/#if]
    [/#list]
    [#return occurrencesCount]
[/#function]

0 in numbers: ${getOccurrencesCount(numbers,0)}
6 in numbers: ${getOccurrencesCount(numbers,6)}
9 in numbers: ${getOccurrencesCount(numbers,9)}
"hello" in words: ${getOccurrencesCount(words,"hello")}
"bye" in words: ${getOccurrencesCount(words,"bye")}
```

output:

```
0 in numbers: 3
6 in numbers: 1
9 in numbers: 1
"hello" in words: 2
"bye" in words: 1
```